# How can I add a Java variable to an xpath in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code snippet looks like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=indexCount;i++){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='assessmentTakerForm']/div/div/div/**div[i]**/div/label/input")).click();
        }
```

My goal is to get that int value 'i' inside that div[]. How can I make it work?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By following :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='assessmentTakerForm']/div/div/div/**div['"+ i +"']**/div/label/input")).click();
```

Comment: clean way to do it (+1). However I would criticize OP for using  this kinda Xpath :  //*[@id='assessmentTakerForm']/div/div/div/**div[i]**/div/label/input